# How does php and condition works

Tags: php

I'm retrieving users from my database with this php code below.

The problem is that when I execute the query without the AND condition, it works fine. With the AND condition it gives me always the else result.

````
   include("config.php");

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pwd,$db) or die('Unable to connect');
if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
   echo "Failed to Connect to Database ".mysqli_connect_error();
}

      $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['contact']);   
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['motdepasse']);   

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM bonfoodUtilisateurs WHERE contact = '$contact' AND motdepasse = '$password'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      $response = array();

      if (mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0) {
         $response['code'] = '1';
         $response['message'] = 'success message.';   
         echo json_encode($response);
         mysqli_close($con);
      }else{
         $response['code'] = '2';
         $response['message'] = 'error message.';
         echo json_encode($response);

         mysqli_close($con);
      }


?>

I'm expecting to get a result like ```{"code":"2","message":"error message."} 
if the user's ```contact and ```password don't exist in the data table
otherwise get ```{"code":"1","message":"success message."}
````

Comment: So there was no matching password in the database.

Comment: Passing password in $_GET?

Comment: How was the password saved?

Comment: in url ```http://localhost/foodios/php/connexion.php?contact=53125353&motdepasse=nuoIZqjFXNB7u+Ho7ndbiw==

I'm giving these values and ```echo($motdepasse) gives me nuoIZqjFXNB7u+Ho7ndbiw== like password

Comment: If you're matching against a plaintext password, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: This is my table fields ``` `id`, `codeuser`, `nomuser`, `contact text`, `adresse`, `positionGPS`, `pointderepere`, `img`, `email`, `dateinscription`, `genre`, `ville`, `adresse2`, `motdepasse text`

Comment: So you are passing the password in plain sight in the address bar of the browser (a hash but still the password). This will be saved in the browser history making the password more or less useless since anyone on that computer can get access

Comment: So please I need help. How it works?

Comment: Oh I see 
just now I made the password shorter and it gave me the expecting result

Comment: That's awesome! Just don't bother checking the password and it will always work.

Comment: Please how can I manage with the password then?

Comment: Have you considered using a post request? or are you just bent on making your logic work to work using a get request irrespective of the parameters?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash

Comment: @BriscoPeasAristide Do some research on password hashing (`password_hash()` and `password_verify()` specifically) and prepared statements

Comment: @PatrickQ Thank you very much, I finally got the expected result thanks to your suggestion ```password_hash() and ```password_verify()